# Проблемы с подключением minio с Djnago

Tags: python, django, minio

Я запускаю django + nginx + minio через compose. Все нормально запускается, он нормально загружает данные в minio, но он почему-то их не выгружает, когда я захожу на любоай endpoint он вместо запроса на /static/, он зачем-то делает запрос на minio:9000/static/. Это у меня уже каталок не варит, потому что я сижу над этим уже 3 часа или что?

settings.py:

```py
public_root = root.path('public/')
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = env.str('MEDIA_URL', default='media/')
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
STATIC_URL = env.str('STATIC_URL', default='static/')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv('MINIO_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv('MINIO_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv('MINIO_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = os.getenv('MINIO_API')
AWS_S3_USE_SSL = False
```

.env:

```
MINIO_ACCESS_KEY_ID=user
MINIO_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=password
MINIO_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME=static
MINIO_API=http://minio:900
```

docker-compose:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: db
    volumes:
      - "~/.pg/pg_data/project:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres

  web:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      context: ./
    container_name: web
    depends_on:
      - db
      - minio
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/project/static
      - media_volume:/project/media
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: >
      bash -c "./manage.py collectstatic --noinput 
      && ./manage.py makemigrations Company Authentication  
      && ./manage.py migrate
      && ./manage.py initadmin
      && gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 project.wsgi:application"

  minio:
    image: minio/minio:latest
    container_name: minio
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"
    volumes:
      - storage:/data
    environment:
      - "MINIO_ROOT_USER=user"
      - "MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=password"
    command: server /data --console-address 0.0.0.0:9001

  createbucket:
    image: minio/mc
    depends_on:
      - minio
    entrypoint: >
      /bin/sh -c "
      /usr/bin/mc config host add --api s3v4 s3 http://minio:9000 user password;
      /usr/bin/mc mb s3/static/;
      /usr/bin/mc anonymous set download s3/static;
      "

  nginx:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      context: ./docker/nginx/
    container_name: nginx
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/project/static
      - media_volume:/project/media
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - web
    ports:
      - "${NGINX_EXTERNAL_PORT}:80"
      - "443:443"

volumes:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
  storage:
```

nginx.conf:

```
upstream project {
    server web:8000;
}

upstream storage {
    server minio:9000;
}

upstream storage_console {
    server minio:9001;
}

server {
listen 80;
#location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://project;
}

location /static/ {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://storage;
}

location /media/ {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://storage;
}

}

server {
    listen 9001;
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://storage_console;
    }
}
```